# Highlight a selection in NSTextField

Tags: macos, highlight, nstextfield

I want to be able to highlight a portion of text in an NSTextField but I've not been able to Google a way of doing this.

I have defined an NSRange but I cannot find a way of using this range to highlight the text. The only thing I have turned up is textField.selectText but this supposedly highlights the whole field.

I'm using Swift 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may have noticed that an `NSTextField` only shows a selection range when it has focus, i.e., is the first responder.  In this case, editing is handled by an `NSTextView` called the field editor.  So, make sure the field has focus (e.g., by using the `makeFirstResponder:` method of `NSWindow`), then use the `NSControl` method `currentEditor` to get the field editor, and then you can use the `NSText` method `setSelectedRange:`.

**ObjC**

```
NSText* fieldEditor = [myField currentEditor];
[fieldEditor setSelectedRange: mySelRange];
```

**Swift**

```
let fieldEditor = textfield.currentEditor()
fieldEditor?.selectedRange = range
```

Comment: textField.setSelectedRange is not available for an NSTextField. It is only available on a NSTextView. :-(

Comment: You call `setSelectedRange:` on the `NSText` returned by `currentEditor`.

Comment: @iphaaw, I forgot to direct my previous comment to you so I'm not sure if you were notified of it.

Comment: sorry for being a nuisance. From what I've read setSelectedRange is not an NSText method either. I'd really appreciate a couple of lines of example code if you have a moment. Thanks.

Comment: @iphaaw: where did you read that?  Here's the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSText/setSelectedRange:).  I'll add a couple of lines in Objective-C, I don't know Swift.

Comment: Thank you for your help.