# NSTextField Cursor Position

Tags: macos, nstextfield, nscontrol

Is there any way of getting the current cursor position in a `NSTextField`? I only find answers to `UITextField` which doesn't work for osx:

```
if let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange{
  let cursorPosition = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument,to: selectedRange.start)
}
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Here's how to set the selected range: [Highlight a selection in NSTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376649/highlight-a-selection-in-nstextfield).

Comment: @Willeke, thanks! Why do you never issue an answer?

Comment: Because short answers are downvoted and in this case a link to an answer isn't an answer.

Answer (score 3):

- Solution 1 (Obtained through NSViewController):

  ```
  let location = (viewController.view.window?.firstResponder as? NSText)?.selectedRange.location
  ```
- Solution 2 (Obtained through NSTextField):

  ```
  let location = textField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange.location
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this snippet to find a cursor location for `NSTextField`:

```swift
let currentEditor = textField.currentEditor() as? NSTextView
let caretLocation = currentEditor?.selectedRanges.first?.rangeValue.location // Int
```