# iOS - Control Input to UITextField from SwiftUI Buttons

Tags: swiftui, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a custom keypad that works with a custom text field. It looks great on the iPhone but not so great on the iPad. I want to control the text field with the buttons of the keypad but not have the keypad as a custom keyboard.

Here is my custom text field:

```
struct WrappedTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    final class ViewModel {
        var placeholder: String
        var text: Binding<String>
        var font: UIFont?
        var textColor: UIColor?
        var viewController: WrappedTextFieldViewController?
        
        init(_ placeholder: String, _ text: Binding<String>) {
            self.placeholder = placeholder
            self.text = text
        }
    }
    
    private var model: ViewModel
    
    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        model = ViewModel(placeholder, text)
    }
    
    // MARK: Modifiers
    func font(_ font: UIFont) -> WrappedTextField {
        model.font = font
        return self
    }
    
    func textColor(_ textColor: Color) -> WrappedTextField {
        model.textColor = UIColor(textColor)
        return self
    }
    
    func viewController(_ viewController: WrappedTextFieldViewController) -> WrappedTextField {
        model.viewController = viewController
        return self
    }
    
    // MARK: Lifecycle Methods
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.inputView = UIView()
        textField.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.textAlignment = .right
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        
        if let viewController = model.viewController {
            textField.inputView = viewController.view
            viewController.addTextField(textField)
        }
        
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.placeholder = model.placeholder
        uiView.text = model.text.wrappedValue
        uiView.font = model.font
        uiView.textColor = model.textColor
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> WrappedTextField.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
}

extension WrappedTextField {
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: WrappedTextField
        
        init(_ parent: WrappedTextField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            if let text = textField.text {
                parent.model.text.wrappedValue = text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the view controller that implements the custom keyboard:

```
final class WrappedTextFieldViewController: UIHostingController<KeypadView> {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(rootView: KeypadView())
    }

    private override init(rootView: KeypadView) {
        super.init(rootView: rootView)
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 370)
    }

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented. Exiting...")
    }
    
    func addTextField(_ textField: UITextField) {
        rootView.wrappedTextField = textField
    }
}
```

Here is my keypad view:

```
struct KeypadView: View {
    @State private var isDisabled: Bool
    
    var wrappedTextField: UITextField
    
    init() {
        wrappedTextField = UITextField()
        
        if let text = wrappedTextField.text {
            _isDisabled = State(initialValue: text.isEmpty)
        } else {
            _isDisabled = State(initialValue: true)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 8) {
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                Button("N") { clickButton("N") }
                Button("S") { clickButton("S") }
                Button("E") { clickButton("E") }
                Button("W") { clickButton("W") }
            }
            
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                Button("1") { clickButton("1") }
                Button("4") { clickButton("4") }
                Button("7") { clickButton("7") }
                Button(".") { clickButton(".") }
            }
            
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                Button("2") { clickButton("2") }
                Button("5") { clickButton("5") }
                Button("8") { clickButton("8") }
                Button("0") { clickButton("0") }
            }
            
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                Button("3") { clickButton("3") }
                Button("6") { clickButton("6") }
                Button("9") { clickButton("9") }
                Button("Del") { clickDeleteButton() }
                    .disabled(isDisabled)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func clickButton(_ buttonText: String) {
        if let text = wrappedTextField.text {
            // Make sure the number is inserted at the cursor.
            if let selectedRange = wrappedTextField.selectedTextRange {
                let cursorStart = wrappedTextField.offset(from: wrappedTextField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
                let cursorEnd = wrappedTextField.offset(from: wrappedTextField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.end)

                wrappedTextField.text = String(text.prefix(cursorStart)) + buttonText + String(text.suffix(text.count - cursorEnd))
                
                if let newPosition = wrappedTextField.position(from: selectedRange.start, offset: 1) {
                    wrappedTextField.selectedTextRange = wrappedTextField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
                }

                isDisabled = disableDeleteButton()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func clickDeleteButton() {
        self.wrappedTextField.deleteBackward()
        
        isDisabled = disableDeleteButton()
    }
    
    func disableDeleteButton() -> Bool {
        if let text = wrappedTextField.text {
            return text.isEmpty
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

My content view for testing:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Label Here:")
                
                WrappedTextField("Press Buttons", text: $text)
                    .viewController(WrappedTextFieldViewController())
            }
            
            KeypadView()
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is a single view with a hidden/disabled keyboard. I know I can keep the keyboard hidden by changing `textField.inputView = viewController.view` to `textField.inputView = UIView()`. But the buttons in the view don't interact with the `UITextField`.

I don't understand how to link the buttons from the `KeypadView` to the `WrappedTextField` when they're not part of the input view as set by `textField.inputView = viewController.view`. The `wrappedTextField` variable updates properly in the `clickButton` function but never propagates to the actual `WrappedTextField`. I suspect I need to change from a `UIHostingController` to something else, but I have very little UIKit experience; I started iOS programming with SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, another day of working on it and fiddling around and I solved it myself. Posted here so people can see how to create an input view with a custom `UITextField` and input from a SwiftUI `Button` (or more than one). The code below creates a fully working custom text field that takes input from multiple SwiftUI buttons.

I wound up referencing these answers to create this solution:

[SwiftUI, change the TextField string from the toolbar button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75571977/swiftui-change-the-textfield-string-from-the-toolbar-button)

[Getting and Setting Cursor Position of UITextField and UITextView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922331/getting-and-setting-cursor-position-of-uitextfield-and-uitextview-in-swift)

`TextHolder` is the model that allows communication between the SwiftUI `Button` and the custom `UITextField`:

```
final class TextHolder: ObservableObject {
    // The shared instance of `TextHolder` for access across the frameworks.
    static let shared: TextHolder = .init()
    
    // The currently user selected text range.
    @Published var start: Int = 0
    @Published var end: Int = 0
    
    @Published var insertionPoint: Int? = nil
}
```

TextFieldRepresentable is the SwiftUI wrapper for the UITextField:

```
struct TextFieldRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    final class ViewModel {
        var placeholder: String
        var text: Binding<String>
        var font: UIFont?
        var textColor: UIColor?
        
        init(_ placeholder: String, _ text: Binding<String>) {
            self.placeholder = placeholder
            self.text = text
        }
    }
    
    private var model: ViewModel
    
    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        model = ViewModel(placeholder, text)
    }
    
    // MARK: Modifiers
    func font(_ font: UIFont) -> TextFieldRepresentable {
        model.font = font
        return self
    }
    
    func textColor(_ textColor: UIColor) -> TextFieldRepresentable {
        model.textColor = textColor
        return self
    }
    
    // MARK: Lifecycle Methods
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        
        textField.placeholder = model.placeholder
        textField.text = model.text.wrappedValue
        textField.inputView = UIView()
        textField.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
        textField.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.textAlignment = .right
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        // Update the actual TextField
        uiView.text = model.text.wrappedValue
        uiView.font = model.font
        uiView.textColor = model.textColor
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Move the cursor forward one if SwiftUI just changed the value
            if let insertionPoint = TextHolder.shared.insertionPoint {
                // only if the new position is valid
                if let newPosition = uiView.position(from: uiView.beginningOfDocument, offset: insertionPoint + 1) {
                    // set the new position
                    uiView.selectedTextRange = uiView.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
                }
                
                TextHolder.shared.insertionPoint = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: TextFieldRepresentable
        var textFieldChangedHandler: ((String)->Void)?
        
        init(_ parent: TextFieldRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func updateTextHolder(_ textField: UITextField) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange {
                    TextHolder.shared.start = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
                    TextHolder.shared.end = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.end)
                }
            }
        }
        
        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            // Start with all text selected.
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
            
            updateTextHolder(textField)
        }
        
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            updateTextHolder(textField)
        }
        
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if let currentValue = textField.text as NSString? {
                let proposedValue = currentValue.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
                textFieldChangedHandler?(proposedValue as String)
            }
            
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

KeypadView is the input view that I plan to use in the popover:

```
struct KeypadView: View {
    @StateObject private var holder: TextHolder = .shared
    @State private var isDisabled: Bool
    
    var label: String
    @Binding var inputText: String
    var placeholder: String
    
    init(_ label: String, text: Binding<String>, placeholder: String = "Required") {
        self._isDisabled = State(initialValue: false)
        self.label = label
        self._inputText = text
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(label)
                
                TextFieldRepresentable(placeholder, text: $inputText)
                    .textColor(.systemBlue)
            }
            .frame(width: 284)
            .padding(.vertical)
            
            HStack(spacing: 8) {
                VStack(spacing: 8) {
                    Button("N") { clickButton("N") }
                    Button("S") { clickButton("S") }
                    Button("E") { clickButton("E") }
                    Button("W") { clickButton("W") }
                }
                
                VStack(spacing: 8) {
                    Button("1") { clickButton("1") }
                    Button("4") { clickButton("4") }
                    Button("7") { clickButton("7") }
                    Button(".") { clickButton(".") }
                }
                
                VStack(spacing: 8) {
                    Button("2") { clickButton("2") }
                    Button("5") { clickButton("5") }
                    Button("8") { clickButton("8") }
                    Button("0") { clickButton("0") }
                }
                
                VStack(spacing: 8) {
                    Button("3") { clickButton("3") }
                    Button("6") { clickButton("6") }
                    Button("9") { clickButton("9") }
                    Button("x") { clickDeleteButton() }
                        .disabled(isDisabled)
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
        }
    }
    
    func clickButton(_ buttonText: String) {
        // Necessary to move cursor to correct location
        let insertionPoint = inputText.index(inputText.startIndex, offsetBy: holder.start)
        TextHolder.shared.insertionPoint = inputText.distance(from: inputText.startIndex, to: insertionPoint)
        
        // Insert the text
        inputText = String(inputText.prefix(holder.start)) + buttonText + String(inputText.suffix(inputText.count - holder.end))
        
        isDisabled = disableDeleteButton()
    }
    
    func clickDeleteButton() {
        let deleteStart = inputText.index(inputText.startIndex, offsetBy: holder.start)
        let deleteEnd = inputText.index(inputText.startIndex, offsetBy: holder.end)
        
        if deleteStart == deleteEnd {
            let correctOffset = holder.start - 1 > 0 ? holder.start - 1 : 0
            let deleteOne = inputText.index(inputText.startIndex, offsetBy: correctOffset)
            
            inputText.remove(at: deleteOne)
        } else {
            inputText.removeSubrange(deleteStart..<deleteEnd)
        }
        
        isDisabled = disableDeleteButton()
    }
    
    func disableDeleteButton() -> Bool {
        inputText.isEmpty
    }
}
```

Here is an example usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = "678"
    
    var body: some View {
        KeypadView("Test", text: $text)
    }
}
```